# External drive (GPT) crashes file explorer in Windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive, mbr, gpt

I was trying to to save data on my external drive which I used a few weeks ago normally (1Tb, NTFS, GPT) but it keeps crashing my file explorer and I am not able to fix it any other way than performing a cold start. The strange thing is that I tried using the external drive on an identical notebook (Dell Latitude 5580) and it worked fine on the other notebook. I also formatted a usb (which worked at mbr formatted and ntfs) to gpt format and it didn't work either, so it seems like that gpt is the problem. I also tried to upgrade all related drivers and did a BIOS update without any success. Do you have any suggestions what I could try next?

Comment: What crash do you get. If there is an error message, please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1687059/edit) your post and add a screenshot.

Comment: It just shows the typical explorer not responding. Unfortunately I couldn't find any related info in the logs.

Comment: The device might be in a bad shape. See if there are errors in its SMART data.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I doubt that, because as I mentioned in the post I formatted a new USB and it didn't work as well when I formatted it to gpt. In my opinion it should be some kind of an issue with the notebook not being able to read an external gpt drive.

Comment: It could also be a problem with the USB port.

Comment: Your opinion has no grounds in reality. Partitioning types are or aren't supported by the OS, it has nothing to do with the computer being a notebook or anything hardware related. And any currently supported Windows version supports GPT anywhere. It is even a requirement for any Windows installed in UEFI mode, i.e., any preinstalled Windows since at least 2012, for the drive containing the system partitions, others can be anything.

Comment: I tried all available USB ports without any success, so I don't think its a port issue.

Comment: It doesnt matter if it is supported or not. It's a fact that the drive doesn't show up in the file explorer or in the disk managemen when it's formatted to gpt.